# How to replace html tag text like label or h1 text before return View from Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, html-parsing

I am working on an ASP MVC .NET 6 Application. The default language of the application is English. Now we have requirements to implement different language options in the admin panel like Spanish, Arabic, etc. We will have a JSON file for each screen/view where all labels text will be set for each label of the screen like in below example:

```
[
{
"LabelHtmlId": "FirstName",
"LablelText" : "User First Name",
"ScreenId": 1,
"LanguageCode: "Eng"
},
{
"LabelHtmlId": "LastName",
"LablelText" : "User Last Name",
"ScreenId": 1,
"LanguageCode: "Eng"
}
]
```

Now the admin will be able to set JSON files for each screen label in different languages like in the above example.
Now our requirement is that we have to call the function just before Return View() in the controller. This function will take the ScreenId and lanuageCode as parameters and will replace all the labels text in the HTML file from the JSON file.
For example, if the label looks like the below:

```
<label id="FirstName">First Name</label>
```

Now after execution of the function just before Return View() in the controller, the above  text will be replaced with:

```
 <label id="FirstName">User First Name</label>
```

because the admin added this text in the JSON file for this label.

Now my problem is that how can I get the complete HTML just before return View line of ActionMethod once all model binding completed with the HTML so that I parse all the labels and replace text from JSON file. Is there any mechanism to apply customer filter on ActionExecuted.

Please do not refer any Front End solution like JavaScript, jQuery because we will not replace the labels text from front end. Its not the requirements. We have to perform all the activity on server side before return View(). If we implement on Front End once page ready, then it will first render the default text and then will replace from the JSON so customer may not face smooth rendering of page.

Thanks

I was thinking to get all the labels from HTML on document.ready and then replace the text of each label from the JSON file using JavaScript/jQuery, but this solution is not feasible because it will affect the smooth rendering of page in browser. Once the default labels will be rendered then it will be replaced from the JSON file so user will feel the labels changing affect from default to selected languages.

I have also the idea of [HTMLAgilityCode](https://html-agility-pack.net/documentation) but in the controller, I don't now how to implement it in the right way after all data binding process with HTML.

Comment: The controller should not "replace" anything in the view. The controller should return a  model to the view and then the view should use that model. Maybe worth looking up what the MVC pattern is in general and how it works before diving into the .Net implementation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0 might help too

Comment: Ok but in controller, you know, the return url of the page is specified. So either we have to perform the activity in the end line of ActionMethod, or in any customer filter when the action method process completed or any other idea?

Comment: Yes, it is a helpful resource for localization. Thanks

Comment: Usually the controller has finished all the processing before the view starts doing it's work. The view may then also render additional views or partial views, so doing the work in the controller is not an option. If you want to implement your own customizations assuming that the native localization doesn't work for you and if you're willing for the view to do independent logic (which is anti-patterns) then you can extend the view logic many ways. Or you could make your own helper methods. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195555/implement-a-custom-mvc-base-view-page

Comment: I don't want to write any helper function for each label individually. In this way, if we add a new view to the application, then we have to call again the helper function for each label and especially if there is come some change later then we have to do for each label. So it will be a headache activity. 

Yes, sure, there are trees of partial views and partial views in each page, so once all partials views and each and every thing are ready, then the localization activity should be performed. Activity should be performed on server side and in once place so that later changes be easy.

Comment: If looking at making a custom helper then it might be something generic, like `Helper.GetTranslatedContentItem("some identifier").HtmlValue` . If you want to manipulate the view after rendering and before returning to the client at a base level for all views, the custom base view page might be an option. At a glance it looks like you could then do something like ` protected override IHtmlContent RenderBody() { var result = base.RenderBody(); //* do something to change the result.*// return result; }`

Comment: Yes, I want the view after rendering and before returning to the server at a base level.
Can you share a little more detail about how to call this generic function once the page render in engine?

Comment: I'm playing around with this answer at the moment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563279/base-view-page-in-asp-net-mvc-6

Comment: Lets me also check this.

Comment: For the record, I think this is a terrible idea and if you do go this route there should be a much more clean and better way to do it than my example I will share. But as a concept only, here is an example:
https://i.imgur.com/eAZGhH3.png

Comment: Have your checked something like this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665582/how-to-display-cshtml-from-model-property-asp-net-core-mvc/69732289#69732289?

Comment: @Joe_DM the idea that you shared in the link is giving more sense. It's really helpful. Actually, there was also a WPF project. So in this project, there was an option for the client to just upload a JSON file for each .xaml screen with language id if he wants to use his own labels. Then before printing the xaml page, there was a localization engine and the job of this engine was to replace all labels text if client specified. So in the web app, now client wants in this way that works like in WPF app.